# How to post the data in Node.js from android using retrofit

Tags: android, node.js, express, retrofit

I am posting the data from Android to the Node.js. I am successfully able to call the Node.js post method and using restify able to get the Post data.
But when doing through express I am not able to get the post body in Node.js. I tried for many approaches from SO post but it seems none are working may be I am missing something.

The snippets are like:

**Node.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var request = require('request')
var http = require('http')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/search/addcomplaint',addComplaint)
function addComplaint(req,res,next){
   console.log(req.body);
   if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
   res.send(201,user)       
}

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

at Android Site I am making a retrofit call like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/search/addcomplaint")
public User search(@Part("complaint") String complaint);
```

when I used restify in Node.js I was able to get req.body but using express I am not getting the request body.

Comment: cay your resolve problem? i have same problem.

Comment: please replace the bodyparser line with app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true})); and tell me if its working